# Validation for checkboxes

Tags: javascript

Hello
I have a JS function which says

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox.length; i++)  
{  
  if(document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox[i].checked)  
  {  
     filteredInitId += document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox[i].value + ",";  
     alert(filteredInitId);  
     isProjCheck = true;  
  }  
}  
document.calDailyBlock.filteredComId.value = filteredInitId;
```

When there are no checkboxes on the page and I try to click on Filter button which calls this function, I receive an error "document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox.length' is null or not an object"

Is there any simple thing which I can add in this function ?

Also can anyone help me how to check if there is only one checkbox on one page ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid the error use an if:

```
if(document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox) {
  for(var i = 0; i < document.calDailyBlock.selFilCheckBox.length; i++)  
  { … }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are relying on a fairly obscure (non-official) feature of some browsers which lets you get an element from the document as if it were an attribute. In other words, you are going:

```
document.calDailyBlock
```

This is searching the document for a variable `calDailyBlock`. Instead, you should use the standardised `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById("calDailyBlock")
```

And use the same approach for getting `selFilCheckBox`.

This will return null if `calDailyBlock` or `selFilCheckBox` are not found. Before you go calling `length` on them (which gives that error), you should check to see if you got back null, and then (I suppose) fail silently (don't do anything).